# Упаковка содержимого папки в tar.gz архив

Tags: linux, tar

Как создать архив из **содержимого** папки (т.е. ее самой в архиве быть не должно)?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/457480/292034

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Зайти в папку и выполнить

```
tar -czf ../имя_архива.tar.gz .
```

Работает и со скрытыми файлами

Answer (score 1):

Зайти в папку и создать архив из всего, что в ней есть:

```
 tar -cf result.tar *
```

Comment: Не будет ведь работать со скрытыми файлами...

Comment: Осторожно, у командной строки есть ограничения на размер. Это плохой совет.